# Remote Build trigger using CURL post call in Jenkins not working

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy, build

**curl -v -X POST http://ci-prd.XXXX.com/jenkins/buildByToken/buildWithParameters?job=RELEASE_XXXXXX_XXXX\&token=askhdbuJHBV&Type=Mexican**

> *Trying 10.14.6.89...
>
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to ci-prd.XXXX.com (10.14.6.89) port 80 (#0)
>     POST /jenkins/buildByToken/buildWithParameters?job=RELEASE_XXXXXX_XXXX\&token=askhdbuJHBV&Type=Mexican HTTP/1.1
>     Host: ci-prd.XXXX.com
>     User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
>     Accept: */*
>
> < **HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**
>
> < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>
> < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>
> < Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>
> < Content-Language: en
>
> < Content-Length: 992
>
> < Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 03:37:58 GMT
>
> - Connection #0 to host ci-prd.XXXX.com left intact

Answer (score 0):

See Jenkins documentation: [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

Below is the line you are interested in:

```
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value
```

Comment: these parameters are not variables these are dynamic and need not ot input manually